# fill the dataframes with dummies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that list clients throughout years.
I'd like to take all customers that ever appear, groupby year week and make every single one appear, if one is not appearing for a specific week i'd like to add None values to the rest of the row but still create a row for this customer
there are multiple years so i'd like it to be for each week of each year
in the end I want to retrieve the complete database with added rows

I tried this but it does not work

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'years': [2021, 2021, 2022],
        'weeks': [1, 1, 3],
        'customers': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
        'cars': [2, 1, 2],
        'pens': [5, 2, 3],
        'furnitures': [1, 2, 4]}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

grouped = df.groupby(['years', 'weeks'])
    unique_customers = grouped['customers'].unique()

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['years', 'weeks', 'customers', 'cars', 'pens', 'furnitures'])

for (year, week), customers in unique_customers.iteritems():
    for customer in customers:
        result = result.append({'years': year, 'weeks': week, 'customers': customer}, ignore_index=True)

result['cars'].fillna('None', inplace=True)
result['pens'].fillna('None', inplace=True)
result['furnitures'].fillna('None', inplace=True)

result.sort_values(by=['years', 'weeks', 'customers'], inplace=True)
result.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


# DESIRED OUTPUT
data = {'years': [2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022],
    'weeks': [1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3],
    'customers': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'cars': [2, 1, None, None, None, 1],
    'pens': [5, 2, None, None, None, 0],
    'furnitures': [1, 2, None, None, None, 1]}

print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Dataframe

[image]

Desired Dataframe

[image]